# Pandas df.shape not outputting anything?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-lab

I have two similar sets (Same Columns, Different Row Count, Possibly different data in some rows) of data from two different databases, and I'm trying to run comparison via Pandas. I'm exporting both datasets to xlsx and then importing into jupyter lab as so:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel("Downloads/file1.xlsx",index_col=None)
df1 = df1.reset_index()
df2 = pd.read_excel("Downloads/file2.xlsx",index_col=None)\
df2 = df2.reset_index()
```

I want to begin the comparison and but when I try to use `.shape`

```
print("---file1---")
print(db2.shape)
print("---file2---")
print(edl.shape)
```

I don't get any return but df2 will return the expected tuple

```
---file1---
---file2---
(20484, 7)
```

If I try to run `print(df1.head(3))` it does properly return the first 3 rows so I know data is making it into DataFrame 1. Same case for DataFrame 2.

I am assuming there is some form of formatting on the data being read from the excel, BUT I'm not getting any errors when calling the command. I could use some help understanding perhaps why `.shape` is not returning anything for df1 but is for df2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should add print to the shape part:

```py
print("---file1---")
print(db2.shape)
print("---file2---")
print(edl.shape)
```

if you don't specify print in the middle of a jupyter cell it won't appear. but if you add it at the end the print() is not necessary.

Comment: I had made an error when initially writing the question, both the df.shape have a print() surrounding them.